# How to connect Play! Framework through Ebean to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm building a Play! Framework (2.5) Java application and I want to connect it to ElasticSearch using Ebean.

First, I followed [the steps here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaEbean) and successfully connected to a dummy jdbc (Added plugin, modified `build.sbt`, added `ebean.default="models.*"`, `default.driver = org.h2.Driver`, and `default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"` to `application.conf`). So far so good.

Now, I want to switch my connection to ElasticSearch instead of jdbc, so I'm following [the steps here](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/features/elasticsearch/get-started), but I can't figure it out for the life of me. What I've done so far:

- Added to `build.sbt`:

  ```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm-elastic" % "1.3.1" )
  ```
- Added to `application.conf`:

  ```
  ebean.docstore.url="http://localhost:9200"
  ebean.docstore.active=true
  ebean.docstore.generateMapping=true
  ebean.docstore.dropCreate=true`
  ```
- Removed from `application.conf`

  ```
  default.driver = org.h2.Driver
  default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
  ```

I cannot get this code to run, because I keep getting this error:

`RuntimeException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: application.conf @ file:/C:/Users/../conf/application.conf: 357-360: docstore has type OBJECT rather than LIST`

I would greatly appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either :

1. Override your ebean configuration programmaticaly
2. Add your configuration in a ebean property file

**1 - Programmatically**

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig;
import com.avaje.ebean.event.ServerConfigStartup;

public class ConfigOverride implements ServerConfigStartup {

    public void onStart(ServerConfig serverConfig) {
        serverConfig.getDocStoreConfig().setUrl("http://localhost:9200");
        serverConfig.getDocStoreConfig().setActive(true);
        serverConfig.getDocStoreConfig().setGenerateMapping(false);
        serverConfig.getDocStoreConfig().setDropCreate(false);
        serverConfig.getDocStoreConfig().setCreate(false);
        serverConfig.getDocStoreConfig().setPathToResources("conf");
    }
}
```

**2 - Configuration**

You have to put your `ebean.docstore` properties in a `ebean.properties` in `conf` directory. But unfortunatly, I didn't manage to make the application work in stage mode

*Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/playframework/play-ebean/master/docs/manual/working/javaGuide/main/sql/JavaEbean.md*

FYI : I opened an issue here :
https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/issues/104